# Magento 1 to 2 migration error, Categories failed

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration

Using UB-Migration tool, Migrating from Magento 1 to Magento 2.
All steps were successful apart from **Step 4 Categories** which failed with below error, please assist.

Error received
Research: I had googled and found that its caused by the source DB(magento 1) not the M2.

I checked table: **catalog_category_entity**
`select * from catalog_category_entity WHERE parent_id is NOT null;`
**returned**: 0 rows effected.

```
2020/12/10 09:42:15 [error] [ub_data_migration] CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'parent_id' cannot be null. The SQL statement executed was: UPDATE `catalog_category_entity` SET `entity_id`=:yp0, `attribute_set_id`=:yp1, `parent_id`=:yp2, `created_at`=:yp3, `updated_at`=:yp4, `path`=:yp5, `position`=:yp6, `level`=:yp7, `children_count`=:yp8 WHERE `catalog_category_entity`.`entity_id`='1193'
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is a question for the UB-Migration tool developers.

Comment: I purchased the tool but my licence expired, i have it running already just encountered error when i decided to move stores.

Answer (score 0):

> **You can migrate using Data Migration Tool :-**

**Install Data Migration Tool**

1. Check your Magento 2 version :- `sudo php bin/magento --version`
2. Install Data Migration Tool from repo.magento.com  :-

   composer config repositories.magento composer https://repo.magento.com
   composer require magento/data-migration-tool:<magento_version>
3. Configure Magento 2 Data Migration Tool :-

   ```
   1 The above file will contain configuration and scripts for migrating from Magento 1 Open Source platform to Magento 2 Open          Source platform.
        <your Magento 2 install dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource

   2 The above file will contain configuration and scripts for migrating from Magento 1 Open Source platform to Magento 2 Commerce.
        <your Magento 2 install dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-commerce

   3 The above file will contain configuration and scripts for migrating from Magento 1 Commerce to Magento 2 Commerce.
        <your Magento 2 install dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/commerce-to-commerce
   ```
4. Configuring the migration :-

   ```
   1 Change to the following directory :-
     <your Magento 2 install dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<migration edition>/<ce or version>

   2 Rename config.xml.dist to config.xml 
     cp config.xml.dist config.xml

   3 Open config.xml in a text editor.

   4 Specify the following at minimum:

           <database host="localhost" name="Magento1-DB-name" user="DB-username" password="DB-password"/>

           </source>

           <destination>

           <database host="localhost" name="Magento2-DB-name" user="DB-username" password="DB-password"/>

           </destination>

           <options>

           <crypt_key>Magento1-Encrypted-Key</crypt_key>

           </options>
   ```
5. Migrate settings :-

   ```
       php bin/magento migrate:settings --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml
   ```
6. Migrate Data :-

   ```
       php bin/magento migrate:data --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml

       php bin/magento migrate:data --auto vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml
   ```
7. Migrate Delta :-

   ```
       php bin/magento migrate:delta --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml

       php bin/magento migrate:delta --auto vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml
   ```

Comment: Thanks, ill test and revert back with feedback